# Immediately dereferencing unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I'm not very familiar with modern C++ and would like to better understand the following fragment:

```
State & m_rootstate;
//...
auto currstate = std::make_unique<State> (m_rootstate);
do_something (*currstate);
// currstate is not used anywhere else
```

I see a `unique_ptr` is created from a reference to a `State`. This should use the copy ctor of `State` to create a new instance of `State`, and a pointer to this new instance gets wrapped in `currstate`.

`currstate` is then immediately dereferenced as an argument to a function. `currstate` is not used after that, but it does not go out of scope until after the call finished so it and its linked `State` do not get destructed prematurely.

For the call, the value inside the `unique_ptr` is used. Depending on whether `do_something` takes a `State` or `State&`, it will be copied again or not.

Is this right? If so, is it correct that the purpose of the `unique_ptr` is only to create a copy of `m_rootstate` without having to worry about memory management?

Comment: From the code posted, it isn't clear there is a need for a `unique_ptr` at all.

Comment: The fragment is utterly pointless and wrong. There's nothing to understand beyond that.

Comment: Where did the code come from? Have you tried to ask the author of it?

Comment: Note: When using `std::make_unique`, you still have to worry about any exception constructor may throw + `std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: What do you mean by _"currstate is not used after that, but **it does not go out of scope** so it and its linked State live on after the call."_?

Comment: @juanchopanza That was my first thought, too, which is why I wrote this question

Comment: @n.m. I don't know. Can you explain why it's wrong? At least the program it is in worked well.

Comment: @YSC I was just stating the obvious there: The scope does not end when calling a function, so the pointer does not get destructed before or during the call, so the linked object also lives until after the call.

Comment: @n.m how so? There are scenarios where this _might_ be the right thing to do. E.g. if do_something mutates its parameter but you for whatever reason you don't want to keep the changes so you pass a copy. And if the State object is too big for the stack you want it dynamically allocated. In this case the code as written seems fine.

Comment: @MikeVine Dynamic allocation is often much slower than automatic allocation. You're also most likely going to incur at-least one unnecessary cache miss.

Comment: @George what? Thats got nothing to do with my point. If the object cant fit onto the stack you've got to use the heap, whether or not that is slower. n.m said it was unequivocally wrong. I'm just giving (admittedly a contrived example) of where it may be correct.

Comment: @MikeVine My bad, only read the first half of your comment.

Comment: @MikeVine if your class type object is too big to fit on the stack, then your code is utterly pointless and wrong, so nothing changes. An array might be too big to fit on the stack, but you don't put fixed size arrays that large in a class.

Comment: @n.m.  why not put large fixed size arrays in a class?

Comment: @n.m "Your" Who said anything about `State` being a class he controls? Sure you can make up scenarios where the code is wrong (which would be the majority) but there simply are scenarios where this code is fine. If your original comment was "Dont do this way unless you have a specific need which forces this" I dont think people would've disagreed.

Comment: I'm not good at imaginary scenarios. I know what I'm doing when I'm seeing this code in a code review: rejecting it. In every single case I've seen such code it was some Java refugee trying to come to terms with C++ pointer semantics. There are no practical legitimate cases for such code. When I see one eyes I may change my opinion.

Comment: @user2079303 why would you? Can you show a legitimate practical case for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
State & m_rootstate;
```

This makes no sense on it's own - im guessing you left vital stuff out. A reference has to be initialized.

```
//...
auto currstate = std::make_unique<State> (m_rootstate);
```

This constructs a new `State` and wraps it in a `unique_ptr` (in this case through a copy constructor, so you are right, its a copy)

```
do_something (*currstate);
// currstate is not used anywhere else
```

*Depending on whether do_something takes a State or State&, it will be copied again or not.* True.

**If so, is it correct that the purpose of the unique_ptr is only to create a copy of m_rootstate without having to worry about memory management?**

In this case, it seems unnecessary to create the `unique_ptr` in the first place.
You might as well just a create a direct stack copy like this:

```
State currstate(m_rootstate);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is this right?

Your description is accurate, yes.

If you mean to ask whether the program is well defined: Disregarding the uninitialized reference at the beginning, there is no code shown that would be either ill-formed or would have undefined behaviour. That said, you didn't show a complete program, so we cannot know whether the complete program is correct.

---

> If so, is it correct that the purpose of the `unique_ptr` is only to create a copy of `m_rootstate` without having to worry about memory management?

Correct. Taking care of memory management of dynamic allocation is indeed the purpose of the unique pointer class. (Or more generally, taking care of releasing a resource).

Note that the shown excerpt doesn't reveal *why* or *whether* dynamic allocation is needed at all. It also doesn't reveal *why* or *whether* a copy is needed. Maybe those things are needed. However, those things should be avoided whenever they aren't needed.